# Where does store pidfiles for filebeat and metricbeat in centos 7

Tags: linux, monit, filebeat, metricbeat

I need to add [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) checker for my filbeat/metricbeat process.
I want to check the process via pid file, but I can't find where the system stores these files in centos 7.

e.g. in my local ubuntu 14.04 it stores under this path **/var/run/filebeat.pid**, **/var/run/metricbeat.pid**.

I have tried to find the file in the whole system (**find / -name filebeat.pid**), but I couldn't.

If there is no why to check via pidfile, do I have another way to check the process state?

Any suggestion would be helpful, thanks in advance )

Answer (score 0):

First get the process id using the name of the executable e.g. filebeat/metricbeat in your case.

Here's an example searching for the *xinetd* process
Search for your process using pgrep:

```
$ sudo pgrep xinetd
1180
```

1180 is the PID of the xinetd process. You can get its arguments like so:

```
$ cat /proc/1180/cmdline 
/usr/sbin/xinetd-stayalive-pidfile/var/run/xinetd.pid
```

If this doesn't specify the pidfile as an argument, you can try *lsof* to list open files associated with the process id.

```
$ sudo lsof -p <Process ID>
```